# Laplace equation in a ring.variable separation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta u=0 \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(a,\theta) = 0 \\
u(b,\theta)=f(\theta)
\end{eqnarray}\tag1$$

Using method of separable variable solve the problem.

My attempt:

Let $u(r,\theta)=h(r)P(\theta)\tag2$ 
Then substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ and dividin we have
$$h''(r)P(\theta)+\frac{1}{r}h'(r)P(\theta)+\frac{1}{r^2}h(r)P''(\theta)=0$$

Dividing  for $h(r)P(\theta)$ and we have:
$$r^2\frac{h''(r)}{h(r)}+r\frac{h'(r)}{h(r)}+\frac{P''(\theta)}{P(\theta)}=0$$

This implies:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{P''(\theta)}{P(\theta)})=0\implies \frac{P''(\theta)}{P(\theta)}=-\lambda$$

Then:
$$r^2\frac{h''(r)}{h(r)}+r\frac{h'(r)}{h(r)}=-\frac{P''(\theta)}{P(\theta)}=\lambda$$

Then we have two equations:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P''(\theta)+\lambda P(\theta)=0 \\
r^2h''(r)+r{h'(r)}-\lambda h(r)=0 \\
\end{eqnarray}\tag3$$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: I assume $0 < a \le r \le b$. And do you want $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$?

Comment: yes @DisintegratingByParts is that

Comment: The initial condition you have is the "Robin" initial condition. See the last example (26.4) of the link provided.  Follow the same idea! 
  https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_26.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to satisfy the periodicity condition for $P(\theta)$, you need $\lambda = n^2$ where $n = 0,1,2,.\dots$ (check this), so the equation for $h(r)$ becomes

$$ r^2 h'' + rh' - n^2 h= 0 $$

which is a Cauchy-Euler equation. The solution has the form

$$ h_n(r) = \begin{cases} 
A_0 + B_0\ln r, & n = 0 \\
A_nr^n + B_n r^{-n}, & n > 0
\end{cases} $$

If you apply the boundary condition $r'(a) = 0$ for each case, you'll arrive at (up to a multiplicative constant)

$$ h_n(r) = \begin{cases} 
1, & n = 0 \\
\left(\dfrac{r}{a}\right)^n + \left(\dfrac{r}{a}\right)^{-n}, & n > 0
\end{cases} $$

By linearity, the general solution is

$$ u(r,\theta) = C_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^n + \left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^{-n}\right]\big[C_n\cos(n\theta) + D_n\sin(n\theta)\big] $$

The remaining boundary condition gives

$$ u(b,\theta) = f(\theta) = C_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-n}\right]\big[C_n\cos(n\theta) + D_n\sin(n\theta)\big] $$

Compare this with the Fourier series of $f(\theta)$ in $(0,2\pi)$ to determine the constants $C_n$, $D_n$

Comment: Excelent answer thanks for take the time un answer to me

Comment: You're welcome! If you're satisfied, feel free to "tick" the answer to close the question

Comment: I have a doubt here.$ h_n(r) = \begin{cases} 
1, & n = 0 \\
\left(\dfrac{r}{a}\right)^n + \left(\dfrac{r}{a}\right)^{-n}, & n > 0
\end{cases}$ i know $u(r,\theta)=h(r)p(\theta)$ then $u_r(r,\theta)=h'(r)p(\theta)$ this implies $h'(r)=0$ and if $n=0$ we have0$\frac{B_0}{r}=0$ then $B_0=0$ this implies $A_0=0$ but you say is $1$ can you give me more details pls?

Comment: $B_0=0$ doesn't imply $A_0=0$? They're independent of each other. The solution is $h_0(r) = A_0$, or $u_0(r)=1$ up to a multiplicative constant.

Comment: oh, true! Thanks :D